# (Py)Mongo can connect remotely but unauthorised when connecting locally

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB instance on a Digital Ocean droplet. I can remote into it using PyMongo and Compass but connecting locally via PyMongo tells me I am unauthorised.

```
Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

### Roles

```
[
{
    "_id" : "admin.normaluser",
    "userId" : ...,
    "user" : "normaluser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "greedymercs"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "admin.rootuser",
    "userId" : ...,
    "user" : "rootuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I can connect remotely using `mongodb://normaluser:<pass>@<ip>:27017/` but connecting locally via `mongodb://normaluser:<pass>@localhost:27017/`fails. I have tried with a default database, rootuser etc and its the same issue every time.

### mongood.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<public ip>

#security:
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Script I am using to test local connections

```
import os
import time

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(os.environ["MONGO_URI"])

now = time.time()

try:
    for i in range(100):
        client.greedymercs.mongoTest.insert_one({"number": i})

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

else:
    print("100 inserts:", time.time() - now)

now = time.time()

try:
    results = list(client.greedymercs.mongoTest.find({}))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

else:
    print(f"Find all ({len(results)}):", time.time() - now)
```

Comment: Do you connect to mongodb://normaluser:<pass>@172.0.0.1:27017/ ?

Comment: The URI I use is in the question, `mongodb://normaluser:<pass>@localhost:27017/`

Comment: Check your /etc/hosts file if you have the entry "127.0.0.1   localhost" or try executing: nslookup localhost

Comment: Yeah it contains it

Comment: If you mondify bindIp: 127.0.0.1,localhost,<public ip> ? , btw in general 'code': 18 is for wrong password ...

Comment: @R2D2 `localhost:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 600c605057cda505f9710657, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('localhost:27017: timed out')>]>`

Comment: So adding ?authSource=admin fixed my issue. I have no idea why since ive tried this before

Comment: By default you where attempting to authenticate to the test database , but yeah it seems your credentials are created in the admin ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added ?authSource=admin  fixed the issue :)